# Supabase getUserByCookie not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, supabase

Trying to test my app on a mobile device, but it won't get cookie from server-side requests. (works as expected on chrome)
when running `getServerSideProps` in Next.js I call:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
  const { user } = await supabase.auth.api.getUserByCookie(req)

  console.log('user from cookie', user)

  if (!user) {
    return { props: {}, redirect: { destination: '/sign-in' } }
  }
  const { data: teams } = await supabase
    .from('teams')
    .select('*')
    .eq('user_id', user.id)

  // do something with the user...
  return {
    props: {
      teams,
    },
  }
}
```

This returns a `user` object when I run the app on Chrome or any other web browser, however, when I try on my mobile device, it fails and returns user = null.

I assume this is something related to the cookie session, any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem with cookies and supabase and fixed it by using my service key for the server side code.

create a new client in your supabase client file and export it.

```
   export const getServiceSupabase = () =>
  createClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
    process.env.SUPABASE_SERVICE_KEY
  );
```

then use this client in your getServerSideProps()